# What's difference between use new or not when i create an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I know there are two ways to create an array with given initial value

1.`int[] ary1 = new int[]{1,2,3,4};`

2.`int[] ary1 = {1,2,3,4};`

What exactly difference between those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your statements will create and initialize an array. However, the following example illustrates a difference:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        // print({ 1, 2, 3, 4 });// Won't be compiled
    }

    static void print(int[] arr) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Comment: if edit it to this way, it can work, why?

        ```int[] ar1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        int[] ar2 = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        print(ar1);
        print(ar2);```

Comment: @theabc50111 - Whatever you have written in the comment is as per the Java syntax. I am glad to see that you have a great curiosity and appetite to learn the concept clearly.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in your example.

However, there is one extra feature that `new type[]` provides - array length:

Like so:

```
String[] names = new String[5];
```

Which makes a new String array with the capacity to hold 5 items. If one of the items is not populated, it will return `null`.

Comment: The `new String[5];` does not have 5 items in it. It has the capacity to hold 5 items but the way it is written each spot is actually null. #1 in how you would populate the array after you call new in a single command.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the following are equivalent.

```
int[] ary1 = {1,2,3,4};
int[] ary1 = new int[] {1,2,3,4};
```

But the `{}` method can only be used when the array is declared. So

```
int[] ary1;
ary1 = {1,2,3,4}; // not permitted.
```

Nor is

```
for (int a : {1,2,3,4}) {
  // do something
}
```

It has to be

```
for (int a : new int[] {1,2,3,4}) {
  // do something
}
```